# How can you create a 3X5 subplot grid where the first 2 cells of the first columns and rows are merged into one large subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, subplot

How can I create a grid of subplots that has 15 subplots originally but 4 of the subplots are merged into a larger subplot so that there are actually only 12 subplots: 11 smaller ones and one larger one.
I have attached an image here that I created with photoshop:
[3x5 subplot grid with a larger subplot in the top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOY7k.jpg)

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html

Comment: @BigBen thank you. I have been trying it like they show but I am too stupid to get the right parameters in brackets to create it appropriately. I already got the larger frame and one layer of smaller subplots around it, I only need to add 2 more layers of subplots to the right side, but I cannot seem to get it right...

Comment: @BigBen, this is what I got 
fig3 = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig3.add_gridspec(3, 3)
f3_ax1 = fig3.add_subplot(gs[:-1, :-1])
f3_ax1.set_title('gs[:-1, :-1]')
f3_ax2 = fig3.add_subplot(gs[0:1,-1])
f3_ax2.set_title('gs[0:,-1]')
f3_ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(gs[1:2, -1])
f3_ax3.set_title('gs[1:, -1]')
f3_ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(gs[2:, -1])
f3_ax3.set_title('gs[1:, -1]')
f3_ax4 = fig3.add_subplot(gs[-1, 0])
f3_ax4.set_title('gs[-1, 0]')
f3_ax5 = fig3.add_subplot(gs[-1, -2])
f3_ax5.set_title('gs[-1, 1]')
f3_ax5 = fig3.add_subplot(gs[-1, -2])
f3_ax5.set_title('gs[-1, -2]')

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the code, instead of posting in a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [Customizing Figure Layouts Using GridSpec and Other Functions](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np                                                                
from itertools import product 

# create a figure, use the best avalable layout and add a gridspec
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True) 
gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 5) 

# three actions

# create a larger subplot that spans rows 0 to 2 (that is, 0 and 1)
# and columns 0 to 2 (again that is 0 and 1)
ax_left_top = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2,0:2]) 

# now the axes on the right, we put them in a list,
# the rows are 0,1, the columns 2,3,4 
axes_right = [fig.add_subplot(gs[r,c]) for r,c in product((0,1),(2,3,4))]

# finally a list containing the axes on the bottom, the row #2
# and all the columns 
axes_bottom = [fig.add_subplot(gs[2,c]) for c in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)]                 

# label the axes for your reference
ax_left_top.annotate('ax_left_top', (.1,.5))
for n, ax in enumerate(axes_right):
    ax.annotate('axes_right[%d]'%n, (0.3,0.5))
for n, ax in enumerate(axes_bottom):
    ax.annotate('axes_bottom[%d]'%n, (0.2,0.5))
```

[image]